# How do you change similar object Types?

Tags: java

User.java (Abstract class)

```
public abstract class User {

  private int id;

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = int;
  }
}
```

Admin.java

```
public class Admin extends User {

  public Admin(int id) {
    super.setId(id);
  }

  public void promoteEmployee(Employee employee) {
    // How would I change the employee object into an admin object? 
  }

}
```

Employee.java

```
public class Employee extends User {

  public Employee(int id) {

    super.setId(id);

  }


}
```

Basically in the method promoteEmployee it takes in Employee object and makes it into an admin object. How would you do that?

Basically

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
```

i want that to turn into

```
Admin employee = new Admin();
```

Comment: You cannot change an object from one type to another once it has been created.

Comment: Method description: "This promotion destroy their current object, loading a new object that represents an administrator." How do you create anew then? I keep getting same variable name error

Comment: Why do you even need Admin class? If you ever use `if (user instanceof Admin)` in your code, then it is very bad design. You are better of using e.g. a Type enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `Employee` and `Admin` both are child class of `User`. there is no relationship (IS-A Relationship) in between the class `Employee` and `Admin`.

Object of `Employee` and  `Admin` class can be hold by the class `User` Reference variable. but there is no such can be done in between `Employee` and `Admin`.

So, whatever code that you have written in your code will achieve the goal you want.

Now I suggest some change into your code to achieve your goal in next edit.

```
public class Admin extends Employee { // change the super class from User to Employee.

  public Admin(int id) {
    super.setId(id);
  }

  public void promoteEmployee(Employee employee) {
    // How would I change the employee object into an admin object? 
  }

}
```

Now here is a relationship between `Admin` and `Employee`. this is a correct relationship in between `Admin` and `Employee`. because each `Admin` is a type `Employee`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem belongs to `patterns` mostly.

**First.** You could use **[Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)** to create new `Employee` based on `Admin`. (e.g. using `new Employee(admin)`)

**Second.** You could use `one` class for both `Admin` and `Employee` and use **[State Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)** to simply change `Admin` to `Employee`. In this you do not create new object and have ability to change objects in both directions quickly (or maybee you have more instances of `User`).

Both approaches have pros and contras. All depend on your goals. In my practise, `Admin` is an `Employee` with extra rights, so I think that `boolean admin` parameter for `Employee` could be enough for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to cast a subclass as another subclass.
You could however take advantage that they extend the same parent class.
Keep everyone as a `User` i.e.

```
User bob = new Employee(2);
User manager = new Admin(1);
bob = new Admin(bob.getId()) // this works!
```

Comment: this works but this is not a correct design pattern to work with. it doesn't defines the correct relationship in between the entity class. Thank You :)